# How to assign task to group in django viewfloe

Tags: django, django-viewflow

Im looking for a solution to assign task to group in viewflow
I Assigned task to user by
.Assign(username='employee')

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of @kmmbvnr answer

1. Create a group in django admin and assign it a permission. For me, I use can manage myflowprocess
2. Assign Users to this group, then after (3.) the tasks will show up in their Unassigned Inbox
3. Add the permissenter code hereion to the View in your flow.

   `my_view_task=  flow.View(MyView, task_title=_('title'), ).Permission( 'myapp.manage_myflowprocess' ).Next(this.next_task)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Django group and add a permission, then use this permission in a flow.View(...). Permission (..)

http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.View.Permission

Comment: Dear it is processor , could you please shown sample as  assign to Manager group

Comment: This is one possible way, but not really useful in real business process.
It would be great if viewflow support **candidate assignees** with variables or **DMN**.  Some references are https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/bpmn20/tasks/user-task/#assignment-expressions
https://camunda.com/blog/2020/05/camunda-bpm-user-task-assignment-based-on-a-dmn-decision-table/

Comment: Viewflow and Camunda  belongs to the different style of software written for the different usage practice. Viewflow written in python and django, and it's codebase 100x smaller. Instead of generic all-cases complex code, desired assignees list implementation for a specific project usecase could be done by creating a custom node and custom queue view for Viewflow is a user project codebase